# Lucene: "breaking" filter/query

Tags: filter, lucene

are there any Lucene filter/queruies, that return the result immediately after finding the 1st match? Has anyone met something like that?

TIA

Comment: You can always search for just one result, of course, but not familiar with anything exactly like that.  Since Lucene works on an inverted index, it finds the search terms in the index, and then follows references to the documents for that term, rather than checking documents for matches in sequence.  So, short circuiting like this doesn't really suit the retrieval model particularly well to my mind.

Comment: It would help if you could explain **why** you need this.

Comment: it's simple: I want to reduce the search time

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is about performances.

A Lucene search process is:

1. **Lookup the terms** you are looking for in the inverted index. Typically there is one bitset for each term. That's **typically fast**.
2. Apply the **boolean query**: Mixing the bitsets using boolean clauses (AND, OR, NOT..): **Typically fast**.
3. Compute the **scoring for each document** found. This is where the performances **can be slow**. It is typically an iteration over all the document found as well as computing the full-text score (vector space model or BM25).

If you are not interested by the full-text score, you may use the [search method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search) which allow to use another sort order and therefore allow to disable the scoring:

```
 TopFieldDocs search(Query query,
                  int n,
                  Sort sort,
                  boolean doDocScores,
                  boolean doMaxScore)
```

You may use the [SortField.FIELD_DOC](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SortField.html#FIELD_DOC) as an arbitrary sorting method.